# Prove that if S is a convex subset then a linear mapping also convex

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $S$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $f: \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb  R^n$ is linear then $f(S)$ is  also convex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: :what are you trying?

Comment: s_1,s_2 are in S and t is in [0,1], so: ts_1+(1-t)s_2 is in S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must show that for $y_1,y_2\in f(S),$ and for $0<t<1$, we have $ty_1+(1-t)y_2\in f(S)$. What does it mean that $y_1,y_2\in f(S)$? The convexity of $S$ and the fact that $f$ is a linear transformation will be essential.

Answer (score 2):

Take two points, $a,b \in f(S)$ . We have to show $\forall t\in [0,1]:  \exists c \in S : f(c) = ta+(1-t)b$.
We know: $\exists x,y \in S: f(x) = a, ~f(y) = b$.

For $t\in[0,1]$ set $c = tx+(1-t)y$, then $c \in S$ $f(c) = tf(x)+(1-t)f(y) = t a + (1-t)b $, because of linearity.